# How to write last recursion for meta-programming template in c++

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I wrote following metaprogramming template:

```
template <unsigned int N, unsigned int P>
struct cutom_imagined
{ 
    static unsigned int function(unsigned int r)
    {
        return (P + N + r) * cutom_imagined<N - 1>::function(r);
    }
};
```

P is actually like a constant. How should I write last recursion for above example? I suppose it should look similar to this one:

```
template <>
struct cutom_imagined<0, /* What should be here? */ >
{ 
    static unsigned int function(unsigned int) { return 1; }
};
```

But don't know how to write it...

Comment: What does P resemble?

Comment: it's just imagined parameter. I'm courious how can I write last recursion in metaprogramming when there are two (or more) parameters in template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `P` part of the template and the specialization. First off, the recursive call is:

```
return (P + N + r) * cutom_imagined<N - 1, P>::function(r);
```

Second, the specialziation is now partial:

```
template <unsigned int P>
struct cutom_imagined<0, P>
{
    static unsigned int function(unsigned int) { return 1; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports `constexpr` you can also do it this like:

```
constexpr unsigned int func(unsigned int r, unsigned int p, unsigned int n)
{
  return (n == 0) ? 1 : ((p + n + r) * func(r, p, n - 1));
}
```